# Want to sort map according object key

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I have a map and his key and value are obejct  like

```
    List<AppointmentRequest> list=AppointmentRequest.findAllAppointmentRequests();
    for(AppointmentRequest a:list){
        Store store=Store.findStore(a.getStoreId());
        map.put(AppointmentRequest.findAppointmentRequest(a.getId()),store);

    }
```

AppointmentRequest contain date column
Now I want to sort this map according this column to show it in jsp page,Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#asList%28T...%29) :

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

Supply a Comparator to the constructor in order to sort the keys by your date column.

It can look like that :

```
Map<AppointmentRequest,Store> map = 
    new TreeMap(new Comparator<? super AppointmentRequest> comparator {
        int compare(AppointmentRequest o1, AppointmentRequest o2) {
            // return -1,0 or 1 based on the relative order of o1 and o2
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please explain more?